# Confused by multiple indented if statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

So I made this really hard to follow method a while ago and I came back to add in another indented if statement to check against an array list of Users using a for loop.
Before I added this in, the method worked fine but now I am getting an error on the last 'else' keyword. It says "syntax error. please delete this token". 
I have no errors when I delete the last else keyword but I'm not sure why when they are four if keywords - should there not be a fourth else keyword? 
Thanks for any help given.

```
//method to validate input by user to log in
public void validateInput() {
    //presence check on username
    if (qi.getEnteredName().length() > 0) { 
        //compare entered username to stored user accounts
        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if (qi.getEnteredName().equalsIgnoreCase(getUserList().get(i).getUsername())) {

                //presence check on password
                if (qi.getEnteredPass().length > 0) {
                    //ensures password is at least 6 char long
                    if(qi.getEnteredPass().length > 5) {
                        qi.getMainCards().next(qi.getPanels()); //getPanels() == cardPanel

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                                "Your password must be at least six characters long.", 
                                "Password Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "Your did not enter a password.", 
                            "Password Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }


            else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "You are not registered.", 
                    "User Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "You did not enter a username. Please try again.", 
                        "Username Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you see what code quality is good for? °_°

Comment: I would refactor that method right away.

Comment: You have two else statements for that if in your for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Well, basically your last two `else` statements are matching up with the same `if` statement which is probably not what you want. You'd have to move the second else statement outside of another `}`. You have this:

```
else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "You are not registered.", 
                "User Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "You did not enter a username. Please try again.", 
                    "Username Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

But you really want this:

```
else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "You are not registered.", 
                "User Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

}else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "You did not enter a username. Please try again.", 
                    "Username Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
```

This is why it's very important to format your code correctly and neatly with proper indentation. In Eclipse (if you're using that) you can select everything and hit ctrl + i (I think) or cmnd + i depending on whether you're using a PC or a mac, and it will properly format your indentation.

That being said, it's probably a lot easier to do `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements than what you're doing here.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `else` statements. 
On the top level you have `if`, `else` and another `else`.

It should be `if`, `else if`, and the ultimate condition would be `else`. If you are dealing with many `if` statements, every next `if` should be `else if`, because `else` means "if everything else is not true".

Answer (score 0):

You missed the right place in your **if** statement, as already mentioned by other answers. To prevent such annoying errors I would recommend to organize the code in more readable manner. For your case it could be something similar to (if I got the logic correctly):

```
public void validateInput() {

    final String name = qi.getEnteredName();
    final String password = qi.getEnteredPass();

    if (empty(name)) { 
        showWarn("Username Violation", "You did not enter a username. Please try again.");
    } else if (!registered(name)) {
        showWarn("Username Violation", "You are not registered.");
    } else if (empty(password)) {
        showWarn("Password Violation", "Your did not enter a password.");
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
        showWarn("Password Violation", "Your password must be at least six characters long.");
    } else {
        // we are good
        qi.getMainCards().next(qi.getPanels());
    }

}

private boolean registered(String name) {
     for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(getUserList().get(i).getUsername())) {
            return true;
        }
     }  
     return false;
}

private void showWarn(String title, String message) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        message, 
        title, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}

private boolean empty(String string) {
    return string != null && !string.isEmpty();
}
```